# Hibernate Mapping List - Index

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, list, indexing

Hi I have problem with my hibernate. When i try to save List to SQLite database it crashes on ID of object stored in the list ... in the database first element gets number 0. The first element of list is succesfully saved but another gives ERROR.

Now what the netbeans says:

SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1 ......

And now my mapped class

WITH LIST

```
<class dynamic-insert="false" table="users" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="DataClasses.User" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false">

    <id name="ID" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <list name="notebooks" outer-join="true" lazy="false" cascade="all" >
        <key column="userID"/>
        <list-index column="ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="DataClasses.Notebook"/>
    </list>

</class>
```

OBJECT STORED IN LIST

```
<class dynamic-insert="true" table="notebooks" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="DataClasses.Notebook" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false">

    <id name="ID" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>

    <property name="name" type="string" />
    <property name="text" type="string" />
    <many-to-one name="subject" lazy="false" outer-join="true" class="DataClasses.Subject" column="subject" cascade="all"/>
    <property name="lastModified"/>       
</class>
```

Comment: I'd appreciate a little more explanation/context of your example(s)...

Comment: I have mapped 2 classes in java 1. called User 2. notebooks. Both are entities and I am trying to store list of notebooks object containing few strings in User. The problem is that this way I've done it, it stores only one notebook in whole database and then it throws that error above. And little about context ... I am trying to make software ... for use on primary schools, that supports online access to some notes from school

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the generator class to "native" - then let the database increment the keys.